# How to export Photoshop shapes to svg with exactly same stroke effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg, shapes, path, cc-2015

I'm not a designer, but I have to export image assets for a website from a PSD layout. I would like to use SVG format for icons for the sake of retina graphics support on the website.

Some icons (shapes) consist of multiple layers, or have stroke effect applied partially on their paths (using *Outside* or *Inside* positions). I don't have *Illustrator*, so I wanted to use Photoshop's CC 2015 *Export As* feature from layer/group right-click menu and then selected SVG.

But some icons **have wrong (double?) stroke size** there, or **have a stroke filling where it wasn't originally**. Both in the preview and exported file. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I can do **in Photoshop** to export them to SVG just the way they look in PSD?

I'm attaching a screenshot collage to show what exactly do I mean.

[image]